# Can anyone identify these PCB connectors?

Tags: pcb, identification, header

I've got a board with 3 headers I'd like to connect to, but I can't identiy them to find suitable mating connectors, can anyone here help, or have suggestions for a reasonably secure alternative way to do it?

[image]

1. Is 13 mm x 6 mm (excluding the rails), I'd guess the pin spacing is around 4 mm, but I can't measure accurately enough - could be a little more or less.
2. 16.5 mm x 7 mm (excluding the latching ramp). Pitch is ~ 5mm
3. 18.5 x 6.3 mm (excluding the rails). Pitch is ~ 6.5mm

Thank you

Comment: The most well-known manufacturers of these kind of connectors are JST and Molex. So start by checking those two, go to each of their sites and search for wire-to-board connectors, sort per pitch.

Comment: Looks potted - can't remove and replace with a different type. If you can't locate a match, you could wrap and solder a short length of wire to those posts, heat-shrink them, and wire those to a new (standard) connector.

Comment: Thanks for that tip - the closest I've been able to find is that #3 looks similar to JST VYH, but there's enough differences that I don't think it's right (also there's no ~4 mm pitch sibling series to match header #1) . I think I'll try getting hold of just the contacts, which I think might be better than nothing, and less permanent than solder.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I've figured this out, though I've thoroughly confused myself with the vagaries of TE connectivity part numbers.

#1 and #3 are both TE Connectivity **Power Double Lock** Connectors.

#1 is the 3.96 mm pitch, 3 position

- Header: 179839-x
- Plug: 177899-x
- Locking plate: 177919 (optional, fits in back of the plug to keep the contacts more secure)

#3 is the 6.5 mm pitch, 3 position

- Header: (1-)179846-x
- Plug: 179938-x
- Locking plate: 316062-1

Both use the same contacts:

- Contact 26 - 22 AWG: 179592-1 or 179592-2
- Contact 20 - 16 AWG: 179593-1 or 179593-2
  These are the part numbers for loose contacts, they're also available in strips.

#2 is also from TE, but the **Power Key 5.0** series

- Header: x-1376383-x
- Plug: x-1376389-x
- Contact 24-20 AWG: 1376348-1 (only available in a strip)
- Contact 20-16 AWG: 1376347-1 (only available in a strip)
- Locking Plate: 1376395-1